# java: abstract classes and its variables

Tags: java, abstract-class

I am fairly new to java so I tried to implement an example and use abstract classes
but my lack of OO knowledge makes me wonder why I cannot use a private variable from the abstract class in a "concrete" class extending it.

Here is my code:

```
abstract class Equation{
    private double[] c;//oefficient
    public static int degree(double[] coeff) {
        return coeff.length;
    }
    public abstract double[] solve();
}

class QuadraticEquation extends Equation{
    public double[] solve() {
        double[] solution;
        double discriminant = c[1]*c[1]-4*c[0]*c[2];
        if (discriminant < 0) {
            solution = new double[] {Double.NaN,Double.NaN};
        }
        else {
            solution = new double[] {(c[1]+Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*c[0])
                                    ,(c[1]-Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*c[0])};
        }
        return solution;
    }
}
```

The Error I get is

```
 c has private access in Equation
```

i could resolve this by making `c` a `public` variable, but I guess there is a better way to do this.

Bottom Line: How do I access the variable `c`.

Comment: Instead of documenting what `c` means with a comment, why not name your variable `coefficient` in the first place? Why is this variable defined in the base class since it doesn't use it at all?

Comment: (1) sorry I forgot renaming it; (2) it is used in the subclass for calculating the solution

Comment: If it's only used in the subclass, then declare it in the subclass.

Comment: but declaring it in every subclass seems like code duplication - and as every equation is determined by its coefficients, it seemed reasonable to put it in the superclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you're looking for is to make `c` protected, so that it will have visibility to subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple,

```
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass World
public       Y         Y       Y      Y
protected    Y         Y       Y      N
no modifier  Y         Y       N      N
private      Y         N       N      N
```

See the table, you have `private` then check if your subclass has access `NO`. You have to use `protected`, or no modifier if it's in the same package but if you change package then cannot acces anymore.

BTW use the most restrictive access level that makes sense for a particular member. Use private unless you have a good reason not to, you have a reason then you have to use another.

Answer (score 0):

you can write an public Getter `public double[] getC() { return c; }` in your abstract class.

Comment: By that logic, why wouldn't we make everything public? Ever heard of encapsulation?